# How to style a Vector layer in QGIS using a numeral of an attribute

Tags: qgis, vector, style

I have a simple vector layer in QGIS that I would like to style with numerals based on the ID attribute.  For instance, point with ID 1 will show up as the numeral 1.  Is this possible with default libraries?

```
wkt_geom             ID
POINT(23.85  37.99)  1
POINT(23.8   37.9)   2
POINT(23.855 37)     3
POINT(23     37.9)   4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understand the question you are asking, but if you are looking to put the number that is stored in the ID column in the attribute field over the point location on a map you can do two very simple things, label by attribute and make the point 'invisible'.

```
1) Label based on the attribute column.
2) Change the point symbology to be a size of zero.
```

By doing this two things you will have the numbers as a symbol, see below.

[image: Source Map]

[image: Labels from attributes]

[image: Zero size symbols]

[image: Final results]

Comment: That's it, sometimes you just don't know the lingo.

Comment: I totally understand. Glad it helped.